# How can I check whether this interval is even running?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, asynchronous, parallel-processing

I've set a bunch of `Console.WriteLine`s and as far as I can tell none of them are being invoked when I run the following in .NET Fiddle.

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Linq;  
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Timers;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    private static readonly object locker = new object();
    private static readonly string pageFormat = "http://www.letsrun.com/forum/forum.php?board=1&page={0}";

    public static void Main()
    {
        var client = new WebClient();

        // Queue up the requests we are going to make
        var tasks = new Queue<Task<string>>(
            Enumerable
            .Repeat(0,50)
            .Select(i => new Task<string>(() => client.DownloadString(string.Format(pageFormat,i))))
        );

        // Create set of 5 tasks which will be the at most 5
        // requests we wait on
        var runningTasks = new HashSet<Task<string>>();
        for(int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
        {
            runningTasks.Add(tasks.Dequeue());
        }

        var timer = new System.Timers.Timer
        {
            AutoReset = true,
            Interval = 2000 
        };

        // On each tick, go through the tasks that are supposed
        // to have started running and if they have completed
        // without error then store their result and run the
        // next queued task if there is one. When we run out of 
        // any more tasks to run or wait for, stop the ticks.
        timer.Elapsed += delegate
        {
            lock(locker)
            {
                foreach(var task in runningTasks)
                {
                    if(task.IsCompleted)
                    {
                        if(!task.IsFaulted)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Got a document: {0}", 
                                task.Result.Substring(Math.Min(30, task.Result.Length)));

                            runningTasks.Remove(task);

                            if(tasks.Any())
                            {
                                runningTasks.Add(tasks.Dequeue());
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Uh-oh, task faulted, apparently");
                        }
                    }
                    else if(!task.Status.Equals(TaskStatus.Running)) // task not started
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("About to start a task.");
                        task.Start();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Apparently a task is running.");
                    }
                }   

                if(!runningTasks.Any())
                {
                    timer.Stop();
                }
            }

        };
    }
}
```

I'd also appreciate advice on how I can simplify or fix any faulty logic in this. The pattern I'm trying to do is like

(1) Create a queueu of N tasks

(2) Create a set of M tasks, the first M dequeued items from (1)

(3) Start the M tasks running

(4) After X seconds, check for completed tasks.

(5) For any completed task, do something with the result, remove the task from the set and replace it with another task from the queue (if any are left in the queueu).

(6) Repeat (4)-(5) indefinitely.

(7) If the set has no tasks left, we're done.

but perhaps there's a better way to implement it, or perhaps there's some .NET function that easily encapsulates what I'm trying to do (web requests in parallel with a specified max degree of parallelism).

Comment: Was there a reason you chose this approach over just pushing tasks into the ThreadPool?  Not saying you were wrong to do this, I'm just curious.

Comment: A simple ActionBlock<T> with a specific DOP would solve the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several issues in your code, but since you are looking for better way to implement it - you can use `Parallel.For` or `Parallel.ForEach`:

```
Parallel.For(0, 50, new ParallelOptions() { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 5 }, (i) =>
{
     // surround with try-catch
     string result;
     using (var client = new WebClient()) {
          result = client.DownloadString(string.Format(pageFormat, i));
     }
     // do something with result
     Console.WriteLine("Got a document: {0}", result.Substring(Math.Min(30, result.Length)));
});
```

It will execute the body in parallel (not more than 5 tasks at any given time). When one task is completed - next one is started, until they are all done, just like you want.

UPDATE. There are several waits to throttle tasks with this approach, but the most straightforward is just sleep:

```
Parallel.For(0, 50, new ParallelOptions() { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 5 },  
(i) =>
{
    // surround with try-catch
    var watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    string result;
    using (var client = new WebClient()) {
         result = client.DownloadString(string.Format(pageFormat, i));
    }
    // do something with result
    Console.WriteLine("Got a document: {0}", result.Substring(Math.Min(30, result.Length)));
    watch.Stop();
    var sleep = 2000 - watch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
    if (sleep > 0)
          Thread.Sleep((int)sleep);
});
```

Comment: One reason I don't want to do that is because it has the potential to flood the site with requests. If I get the first 5 responses very fast, I still want to wait a second or two before making the next batch of requests.

Comment: Do you know how exactly site restricts concurrent request? I mean, something like "no more than X requests in Y seconds".

Comment: No, I don't. But let's suppose I did: then what would be the procedure in terms of X and Y?

Comment: You really shouldn't do `new WebClient().DownloadString(` as `WebClient` is `IDisposable`.

Comment: @Enigmativity while true in general, WebClient's Dispose does nothing useful (it is IDisposable just because it inherits from IComponent), so it makes no harm to not dispose it (not leaves any open streams, pending web requests or something like that).

Comment: @Evk - It does nothing useful now, but we can't be sure it won't in future releases. It has an `IDisposable` contract and I think it needs to be honoured. That's partly what OOP is about - the implementation is irrelevant and the contract is king.

Comment: Well you are right of course, it's just very common pattrern with those classes (even popular books like C# 5.0 in a Nutshell say Dispose can be ignored for them). By the way disposing has one more benefit - it will supress finalizer so object will be collected faster.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't a direct answer to your question. I just wanted to suggest an alternative approach.

I'd recommend that you look into using Microsoft's Reactive Framework (NuGet "System.Reactive") for doing this kind of thing.

You could then do something like this:

```
var query =
    Observable
        .Range(0, 50)
        .Select(i => string.Format(pageFormat, i))
        .Select(u => Observable.Using(
            () => new WebClient(),
            wc => Observable.Start(() => new { url = u, content = wc.DownloadString(u) })))
        .Merge(5);

IDisposable subscription = query.Subscribe(x =>
{
    Console.WriteLine(x.url);
    Console.WriteLine(x.content);
});
```

It's all async and the process can be stopped at any time by calling `subscription.Dispose()`;

Comment: Won't hurt to add how to throttle requests in this case (author needs for example that at least two seconds has passed between each batch of 5 requests).

Comment: @Evk Rx It's far easier to throttle with Rx, it already has operators to throttle or buffer events

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos yes but since it's an answer would be good to describe how exactly to do that in this particular situation.